# How to apply typing to object property names so only valid CSS properties are allowed?

Tags: typescript

I have an object representing CSS:

```
{
color: "red",
position: "absolute",
display: "none"
}
```

The property names color, position, display etc are dynamic (can vary) and I pass this object to different functions. How can I apply typing to the property names to ensure only valid CSS properties are allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an interface called `CSSStyleDeclaration` defined in `lib.dom.d.ts` which you can use. The properties in it are all required, so if you want a subset you will also need `Partial`:

```
let c: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> = {
  color: "red",
  position: "absolute",
  display: "none"
  foo: "" // Error
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=2#code/DYUwLgBAxgXBAKBDATmAlo4AeAwgZQLAE9QAREKYFRdAewDsA+CAXggG8AoCaW4W5HABEyEABMhAGm4QADrQDOaOvWGIARgr4BXMCCkyxaBbKpFh9BvpkAzWrWFCIAemcQAosmQDOAXyA)